# how to create linux directories and sub directories structure without files from it

Tags: linux, file-copy, directory-structure

I got requirement to create mirror image of existing Linux directories and sub directories of folders as below.

we have "/opt/current" directory which has another layer of 20 sub directories  and one more layer with 50 sub directories and so on...few more deeper layer for sub-directories and total we have 1000 directories from parent to child.
the /opt/current is mounted on Oracle ZFS appliance.

How to create exact mirror directories/sub-directories structure in new location /opt/New not manually like one to one directory and apply permissions.
the /opt/New is mounted on another ZFS appliance.

Is there a way/script to create entire directory structure from parent to child with same owner/group/other permission in /opt/New path as in /opt/current path?

thanks,
CG

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync -av --include='*/' --exclude='*' /opt/current/ /opt/New
```

This would use `rsync` to exactly duplicate the directory structure of `/opt/local` in `/opt/New` while avoiding copying any files.

The `-a` option (`--archive`) would make sure that all permissions etc. are preserved (this option also implies a recursive copy), and `-v` (`--verbose`) would be giving you an indication of the progress of the command.

With `--include='*/'` we explicitly include any directory in the transfer, but exclude everything else with `--exclude='*'`. The ordering of these to options on the command line is important.

The `/` at the end of `/opt/current/` is also important, as without it, the result would be to create `/opt/New/current` instead of writing into `/opt/New` directly.

Comment: thank you.. i will test this.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly and assuming directory names don't contain newline characters, and `$srcdir` and `$dstdir` are absolute paths:

```
(cd -P "$srcdir" && find . -type d | pax -rwdpe "$dstdir/")
```

Some `pax` implementations support getting NUL-delimited lists of files to copy with a `-0` option to allow filenames with NULs:

```
(cd -P "$srcdir" && find . -type d -print0 | pax -0rwdpe "$dstdir/")
```

(`-print0` is also a non-POSIX extension).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `rsync`

```
find /opt/current -type d -print0 | cpio -0pma backup/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

`mtree` is designed for just this sort of task.

```
# mkdir /opt/New
# mtree -cdp /opt/current | mtree -Up /opt/New
```

FMI, [see this cross-site duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1389580/copy-directory-structure-only-at-year-end/1389998#1389998).

Answer (score -2):

You can make  a script like the following...
put that in a file:

-- bash script/ksh script syntax will need to change depending on shell ----

```
find . -name "*"|while read line
do
        if [[ -d ${line} ]]
        then 
                echo ${line}
        fi
do
```

on server you are making the file

```
cat file |while read line
do
mkdir ${line}
done
```

Comment: Note that `-name "*"` will match anything, so it can be deleted. You may also use `-type d` with `find` instead of the `[[ -d $line ]]` test.  Also note that `read` strips flanking whitespace off from the strings that it reads by default, and interprets backslash under some circumstances, so you may want to use `IFS= read -r line` instead. But using `-type d` with `find` would get rid of that loop anyway. The `mkdir` bit would unfortunately not preserve the meta data of the original directories, which was one thing that the user wanted to do.

Comment: yep.. i was just giving a simple "quick and easy" thing.. There are about 10k ways to do this. Given that the user wants to replicate the directory structure only, I wouldn't do anything "rm: ... I would simply make a report of the directory structure on one box, then duplicate that on the other... your "find" command would absolutely work much the same way dumping that info to a file for sure.